# Powershell to truncate a string

Tags: string, powershell, substring, truncation

I'm trying to truncate a string which I'm fetching from an excel file.

The string(URL) is: **;#://abc.com/sites/abcx/000000103483/default.aspx;#000000103483;#**

I need it to be: **abc.com/sites/abcx/000000103483/**

But the problem is **abcx** in the URL ranges from **abcx** to **abcxxxx**, where x is an integer.

How can I get the required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, you could split on `/`s and build the string you want like this:

```
$string = ";#://abc.com/sites/abcx/000000103483/default.aspx;#000000103483;#"
$split = $string.Split("/")
$split[2] + "/" + $split[3] + "/" + $split[4] + "/" + $split[5] + "/"
```

Output:

```
abc.com/sites/abcx/000000103483/
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `default.aspx` and everything that comes behind it.

```
$s = ';#://abc.com/sites/abcx/000000103483/default.aspx;#000000103483;#'
$s -replace 'default\.aspx.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

try using -match and indexOf to find the position of the start and end phrase

```
$url="xxx://abc.com/sites/abcx/000000103483/default.aspx;#000000103483;#"

$search_start="xxx://"
$search_end="/default.aspx"

if ($url -match $search_start)
{
    $start=$url.IndexOf($search_start) + $search_start.Length
}

if ($url -match $search_end)
{
    $end=$url.IndexOf($search_end)-$search_end.Length
}

cls

$splice=$url.substring($start,$end)

Write-Host "($start) ($end) $($splice)"
```